# Can Rhapsody be configured to use an external source code editor?

Tags: linux, emacs, emacsclient, rhapsody

I am using Rational Rhapsody for Linux and is wondering if it is possible to configure it to open source code with an external editor instead of the built in editor. I would prefer to be able to edit code using emacs via emacsclient.

According to the documentation the following procedure should set Rhapsody to use an external editor but editing that property has no apparent effect when I attempt to edit the code of one of my classes.

1. Select File > Project Properties.
2. Select the Properties tab.
3. Navigate to the General::Model::EditorCommandLine property.
4. Click in the property value call in the right column to activate the field, then click the ellipsis (...) to open the Browse for File window.
5. Browse to the location of the editor you want to use (for example, Notepad) and select the editor. Click OK to close the window. The product displays the path in the property value field.
6. Click OK.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the Rhapsody Eclipse Workflow integration?  With that you can open your Rhapsody Model inside Eclipse, and use Eclipse as editor too.

Be careful, not all features from Rhapsody are available this way.

Comment: I have but my editor of choice is Emacs and I have personalized it quite a bit to make my work more effective. Eclipse would only give me minor feature additions when it comes to code navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I have only used Rhapsody on Windows, but you have to click the "..." button to get it to break out to the external editor to edit something that showing in the properties dialog.  If you want to use the external editor in this way, you have to use one that Rhapsody can execute, and then wait for it to exit, as Rhapsody will create a temp file, open the editor on the temp file, and then import the temp file back into the dialog when you close the editor.

Comment: After further investigation I am starting to believe that this feature is broken in the Linux version.